# Strange order of firing of Validation.Error event - Added fired before Removed causing wrong validation results WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, infragistics

In my WPF application,recently we upgraded Infragistics control version from 9.2 to 17 series. Due to that, framework also upgraded from 3.5 to 4.0.
Post this upgrade, existing working functionality stopped working.

I am getting strange behavior as far as order of firing of Validation. Error event is concerned. Earlier removed action used to be fired before added which was returning correct validation error
Post upgrade, Added action is firing before removed due to that added validation error is getting removed and causing wrong code execution and giving popup to save the data instead of validation error.
Here is the code that I am using.

XAML code

```
<TextBox Width="220" Grid.Column="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
    Foreground="{Binding DataContext.ForegroundColor,
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
       Validation.ErrorTemplate="{DynamicResource validationTemplate}" 
          Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"
                MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick"
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource TextBoxContextMenuForSearch}"
                ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
                ContextMenuOpening="TextBox_ContextMenuOpening">
            </TextBox>
```

CodeBehind

```
private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     System.Windows.Controls.Validation.AddErrorHandler(temp, new 
     EventHandler<ValidationErrorEventArgs>(ValidateTextBoxInput));

     }

    //Method which is bind to event handler

     public void ValidateTextBoxInput(object sender, 
     ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
     {
        TableDetailsDataViewModel tempviewModel = (ViewModel as 
        TableDetailsDataFormViewModel).ParentViewModel;
        if (tBe)
            return;
        if (!fromRecordChanged)
            return;

        TextBox txtWarning = sender as TextBox;
        if ((ViewModel as TableDetailsDataFormViewModel).RecordManagement.CurrentItem != null)
        {
            DataRow row = ((DataRowView)(ViewModel as TableDetailsDataFormViewModel)
                                .RecordManagement.CurrentItem).Row;

            BindingExpression be1 = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(sender as DependencyObject,
                TextBox.TextProperty);

            BindingExpression be = e.Error.BindingInError as BindingExpression;
            if (be != null)
            {
                if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
                {
                    DataRow[] drow = tempviewModel.Errors.Select(tempviewModel.Errors.RowIDColumn.ColumnName + "='"
                          + row.GetHashCode().ToString() + "'" + " and " + tempviewModel.Errors.ColumnInErrorColumn
                          + "='" + be.ParentBinding.Path.Path + "'");
                    if (drow != null && !drow.Any() && be.ValidationError!=null)
                    {
                        TableErrors.ErrorListRow errorRow = tempviewModel.Errors.NewErrorListRow();
                        errorRow.ColumnInError = be.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
                        errorRow.Messgae = e.Error.ErrorContent.ToString();
                        errorRow.Rule = (be.ValidationError.RuleInError as ValidateBase).RuleName;
                        errorRow.RowID = row.GetHashCode().ToString();
                        errorRow.Value = (sender as TextBox).Text;
                        tempviewModel.Errors.AddErrorListRow(errorRow);

                        row.SetColumnError(be.ParentBinding.Path.Path,
                           (e.Error.ErrorContent.ToString()));
                    }
                }
                else
                {   
                    DataColumn[] errColumns = row.GetColumnsInError();
                    Dictionary<string, string> errMessages = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    foreach (DataColumn errColumn in errColumns)
                        errMessages.Add(errColumn.ColumnName, row.GetColumnError(errColumn));

                    row.ClearErrors();
                    DataRow[] drow = tempviewModel.Errors.Select(tempviewModel.Errors.RowIDColumn.ColumnName + "='"
                            + row.GetHashCode().ToString() + "'" + " and " + tempviewModel.Errors.ColumnInErrorColumn
                            + "='" + be.ParentBinding.Path.Path + "'");

                    if (drow.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in drow)
                        {
                            tempviewModel.Errors.RemoveErrorListRow(dr as TableErrors.ErrorListRow);
                        }
                    }
                    if (errMessages.ContainsKey(be.ParentBinding.Path.Path))
                        errMessages.Remove(be.ParentBinding.Path.Path);

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> col in errMessages)
                    {
                        row.SetColumnError(col.Key, col.Value);
                    }
                }                                  
            }
        }
    }
```

Has anyone come across this issue? since it was working code,i am not getting what changes needs to be done to fix this issue?Please suggest

Comment: anyone has any solution to this issue related to WPF which occured post upgradation to .Net 4.0 ?

Comment: I am still looking for solution.kindly let me know if someone has any solution.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm in the same situation. The *Added* event is fired then *Removed* event is fired when I go from an invalid input (so it removes this and the errors are cleared) to another invalid input (added and then removed such that there are no errors when there should be one).